# Drupal site Phonegap application field collection

Tags: entities, ajax

I'm in the process of making a Phonegap application to create nodes of a certain content type. The site I'm writing data to/getting data from utilises [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/field_collection) module, and I've looked at the database structure. It creates additional tables for the contained fields and cross-references them. I was wondering if anyone has come across this situation and how did you manage to solve it.

Note:

I'm using [Drupal Services](https://www.drupal.org/services) for endpoint,  and my request needs to send all those fields in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kartagis/db7Logua/1/) altogether (more than one row).

As for what the fiddle does, I'm creating a table then add more rows to the table.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify your problem. Your fiddle doesn't have any AJAX calls. What's your request need to send? What is the endpoint doing? What are you using for your AJAX endpoint?

Comment: I don't know if this would help but using the module field collections, the  field collection items are saved in the table `field_collection_items` and all the fields inside the field collection are stored in their own table (normal drupal way). Then inside the fields there is a column called `bundle` which holds the value of the `field_name` from the field collection item, creating a 1:m relationship. You can insert into the `field_collection_item` table then loop through the field values and insert them one by one adding the relationship through the bundle col

Comment: Why is the question being voted as closed? Isn't it a legit one?

Comment: To answer the comment about "why voted as closed": there are currently 2 votes (not from me) that indicated this: "unclear what you're asking. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.". So I think it's in "your" hands to (soon) enhance your question, eg to answer to Shawn's comment also. If we don't understand the question, we cannot answer it, you must understand that, no? Just trying to help, ok?

Comment: @DMAC : why not rework your comment above as a possible "real" answer? Give it a try!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens please see my edit in the question (sorry that it overrode yours)

Comment: No need for sorry, you're on the right track by enhancing your question (and integrating relevant comments), Don't forget to also delete comments that are now integrated in the enhanced question. Maybe (if you can), add some more details about what the fiddle is supposed to do/show, etc, ok?

Comment: @Kartagis It's not clear where you are having troubles. Do you have how to create a service endpoint to create nodes? It doesn't seem relevant that this is a phonegap app? It would help a lot if you explained what you have done and where you have done, as this otherwise would be a "do my homework" type of question.

Comment: @googletorp I have created my endpoints and am already fetching data, but I am having trouble writing field_collection data, as its structure seems so complicated.

Comment: make sure a field collection exists if you want to go through the `Field collection` module. Then write the custom php code make sure to use the [field collection api](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!field_collection!field_collection.api.php/7). here is an [example](http://rapiddg.com/blog/programmatically-adding-field-collection-item-node-drupal). another [example](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477186). they are everywhere. You will have to use AJAX from your phone gap app and send the data you are collecting to your server then use the drupal code to process and insert.

Comment: [AJAX from phonegap to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046815/can-i-use-phonegap-jquery-to-make-ajax-calls#answer-7046952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure a field collection exists if you want to go through the Field collection module. When writing code make sure to use the field collection API. See the examples on [Programmatically Adding a Field Collection Item to a Node in Drupal](http://rapiddg.com/blog/programmatically-adding-field-collection-item-node-drupal) or 
[Example: Programmatically adding field collection entries to a node](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477186)
.

You will have to use AJAX from your PhoneGap app, send the data you are collecting to your server, and use code to process and insert, as shown on [Can I use PhoneGap jQuery to make AJAX calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046815/can-i-use-phonegap-jquery-to-make-ajax-calls#answer-7046952)

Comment: I have a bunch of other fields than field collection. Do I need to process all of them by making an ajax call to a PHP file, or is it okay if I do the field_collection only by PHP, and the rest as usual?

Comment: If you are using a javascript front end then yeah, Best practice is to validate the values on the front end, then if passed validation AJAX the data to the server on submit, then re-check the values on the server side, then insert into drupal, then send the response variable back to the AJAX call on the frontend and set the appropriate event action/messages. Drupal has an API already so you can utilize that in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can send **JSONP Cross-domain Requests** using ajax call in your **PHONEGAP** application. [Cross Domain Request](https://www.json.com/json-tutorial/send-jsonp-cross-domain-requests)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://remote.domain.com/data/?allback=jsonpcallback&id=123",
    jsonp: "jsonpcallback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
    id: "123"
  },
  success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
   }
});

 function jsonpcallback(data) {
  //do stuff with JSON
    console.log(data);
 }
```

Then you can get all post data and save to particular content type using drupal bootstrap.